# Why are package imports needed in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, ecmascript-6

About a year ago I have used Meteor, and now I want to use it again, but many things have changed.

When I follow the Blaze tutorial on Meteor.com, they add imports on top of their files:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveDict } from 'meteor/reactive-dict';
```

I got the app working. But when I comment the imports out, the app keeps working like it should work. Why are these imports needed?

I am still using the regular Javascript, not ES6.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're not using ES6, you can't use the import syntax unless you have a module bundler that recognises it.

Comment: Ah I already thought it had to do something with ES6. But what's the main advantage of using imports?

Comment: It's not specific to Meteor, but there's a module bundler called Rollup that uses *tree-shaking* to remove stuff you don't need, and it only works with ES6 modules. Check it out, it's awesome ;)

Answer (score 3):

The import statement is used to import functions, objects or primitives that have been exported from an external module, another script, etc.

The name parameter is the name of the object that will receive the exported members. The member parameters specify individual members, while the name parameter imports all of them. name may also be a function if the module exports a single default parameter rather than a series of members. Below are examples to clarify the syntax.

Import an entire module's contents. This inserts myModule into the current scope, containing all the exported bindings from "my-module.js".

For more detail about the different ways we can use import along with their usage, please check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import).

Answer (score 1):

They still use the old globals for backwards compatibility. However it is recommended to use the imports so if in some future release they remove the globals your code will still work. You can read more in the [appropriate section of the guide](https://guide.meteor.com/1.3-migration.html#modules).

Comment: Allright so it's kind a fallback for if they ever gonna remove the globals?

Comment: Thats my take on it. However, I don't think they ever will remove the globals.

Answer (score 1):

Ok you know `import` is to import an exported object from another file already.

The point that you may have missed is that MDG heard the need to stop loading everything by default, or at least to provide a mean to control what is loaded in memory and what is not.

Look for the [`/imports`](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#special-directories) special directory.

Files in that folder are no longer loaded automatically, but only through `import` statement.

As for the tutorial, I guess they did not explained this functionality, and because it imports only standard functionalities which are still loaded eagerly for backward compatibility, it does not change anything removing those statements.

Comment: Importing other files from the /imports folder using `import { Tasks } from '../api/tasks.js';` sounds logical, but I dont get why you should import packages like `import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';`, if it doesn't do anything anyways.

Comment: I would say both good practice and "just in case" as Sean Hayes mentioned?