# Is Import needed to run Meteor app

Tags: javascript, meteor

This Meteor template code is the default generated when `meteor create myApp` is invoked. In `main.js` the first 3 lines are:

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';
import './main.html';
```

But when I comment them out, the app still runs. Reading the [docs](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html) could not answer my question, Why do we need the `import` statement if the app still runs without them? Thanks

Comment: The app *runs* but does it run *in the desired way*?

Comment: @AndrewL. Could you explain the _desired way_ in a bit more details?

Comment: Does it load HTML and everything that you've programmed?

Comment: @AndrewL. yes. every thing. I actually wrote another Meteor app and don't remember ever using `import` and all worked fine. Then why do we need it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38742073/why-are-package-imports-needed-in-meteor/38744468#38744468

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Earlier versions of Meteor relied heavily on using the global namespace for accessing shared libraries. As of Meteor 1.3, you can now use [Meteor's ES2015 module](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#es2015-modules) support. This means you can use import/export functionality to expose access to various parts of your codebase, without having to rely on globals. Using imports/exports is now the preferred/recommended way of referencing parts of your application, so `meteor create` functionality was updated to demonstrate this. As you mentioned, you can remove the `import` statements above and you will still be able to access `Template` and `ReactiveVar` globally (for backwards compatibility). It's important to note however that this might change in the future - Meteor has fully embraced ES2015 module support, and could potentially drop the use of globals completely (well, to the extent possible).

One more thing to note - Meteor 1.3 also introduced new "lazy-loading" functionality, wherein application code stored under an `/imports` directory will no longer by eagerly loaded when the application starts up. Code stored under an `/imports` directory will only be loaded if it's referenced by an `import` statement somewhere else in your codebase. See [Special directories](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#special-directories) for more info.